# pthread_join and pthread_create

Tags: pthreads

I am a rookie in multi-thread programming. Here I wrote a small program to compute the square root from 0 to 20. The size of my thread_id array is 3. My strategy is like asking thread_ID[0] to compute square root of 0,3,6...and thread_ID[1] to compute 1,4,7...
But the result seems to have some problems. There are duplicate results.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define THREAD_NUM 3

void *thread_function( void *arg )
{
    int *incoming = (int*)(arg);

    double result = sqrt(*incoming);
    printf("The square root of %d is %f\n ",*incoming, result);
    return NULL;
}

int main( void )
{
    pthread_t thread_ID[THREAD_NUM];

    void *exit_result;
    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
    {
        int id = i%THREAD_NUM;
        int num = i;
        if( i >= THREAD_NUM )
        {
            if(pthread_join( thread_ID[id], &exit_result ) != 0)
                perror("join failed");
        }

        if( pthread_create( &thread_ID[id],NULL,thread_function,&(num)) != 0)
            perror("create failed");

    }
    for( i = 0; i < THREAD_NUM; i++ )
    {
        pthread_join( thread_ID[i], &exit_result );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result is

The square root of 2 is 1.414214
 The square root of 3 is 1.732051
 The square root of 2 is 1.414214
 The square root of 4 is 2.000000
 The square root of 5 is 2.236068
 The square root of 7 is 2.645751
 The square root of 8 is 2.828427
 The square root of 6 is 2.449490
 The square root of 9 is 3.000000
 The square root of 10 is 3.162278
 The square root of 12 is 3.464102
 The square root of 13 is 3.605551
 The square root of 11 is 3.316625
 The square root of 14 is 3.741657
 The square root of 15 is 3.872983
 The square root of 16 is 4.000000
 The square root of 18 is 4.242641
 The square root of 17 is 4.123106
 The square root of 19 is 4.358899
 The square root of 19 is 4.358899

Comment: Please format code and also add to the question the output you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You've only got one integer for all of your threads.  Specifically:

```
int num = i;
```

When you call

```
pthread_create( &thread_ID[id],NULL,thread_function,&(num))
```

Then the address of `num` is passed to the thread.  Now in each created thread, you use this address as follows:

```
int *incoming = (int*)(arg);
```

So, `*incoming` is going to be a pointer to `num` from the main function.  The thing is, it's going to be a pointer to the *same* `num` that every other thread is using.  And you keep changing the value of `num`.  As such, every thread is just going to be looking at the last value you set for it.

Comment: Yes.  Plus, it's not such a great idea to create and join threads over and over to perform such trivial work on a single value.  Sounds like a good place to either partition the workload ahead of time (pass each thread a range of values to work on independently), or use a thread pool.  The latter is definitely overkill for a problem this small.

Comment: I understand it's really not a good design, just wanna know what causes that. OK, now I totally understand, thanks guys!